# How to filter data from postgresql which has jsonb nested field in the array field of jsonb?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js, jsonb

i have a table with a jsonb column and documents are like these(simplified)

```
{
      "a": 1,
      "rg": [
        {
          "rti": 2
        }
      ]
    }
```

I want to filter all the rows which has 'rg' field and there is at least one 'rti'field in the array.

My current solution is

```
log->>'rg' ilike '%rti%'
```

Is there another approach, probably a faster solution exists.

Comment: your sample input seems invalid for a jsonb object.

Comment: Problem is not the json correctness, they are correct normally this is a sample.

Comment: yes, now I'm able to insert to data for the jsonb column.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be applying `jsonb_each` to the jsonb object and then `jsonb_array_elements_text` to the extracted value from `jsonb_each` method :

```
select id, js_value2
  from 
(
select (js).value as js_value, jsonb_array_elements_text((js).value) as js_value2,id
  from
  (
   select jsonb_each(log) as js, id
     from tab
  ) q
  where (js).key = 'rg'
) q2 
where js_value2 like '%rti%';
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=a125cfd223359cc2a4cfc90e5bd61fde)</kbd>